# Discord.py create an embed message command

Tags: discord.py

I was trying to make a embed command with time limit, só i started doing it, and at my first try to make it timed it didn't work.
So i searched here, found one sample and tried to do like it (as you can see at my code below), but it didn't work too.
Then i tried to copy that code and pasted at my bot.
Guess...it didn't work -_-, now i'm here, asking gods to help.

```
client.command(aliases=["createEmbed", "embedCreate"])
async def embed(ctx,):
    Questions = ["Titulo?", "Cor? (Hex sem #)", "Descrição?"]

    Responses = []

    def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel

    #try:
    await ctx.send(Questions[0])
    title = await client.wait_for('message',timeout=2.0,check=check)
    
    #except asyncio.TimeoutError(*title):
     #await ctx.send("Demorou muito")
     #return
    
    #else:
    Responses.append(title.content)
    await ctx.send(Questions[1])

    cor = await client.wait_for('message',timeout=25.0,check=check)
    Responses.append(cor.content)

    await ctx.send(Questions[2])
    descrição = await client.wait_for('message',timeout=25.0,check=check)
    Responses.append(descrição.content)
    
    cor2 = Responses[1]
    corHex = int(cor2, 16)
    
    embedVar = discord.Embed(title=Responses[0], description=Responses[2], color=corHex)
    await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)
```

At my code you can see the piece with #, that is the piece that i tried to test the time command.
If i remove the time command, it works.

Comment: Your wait_for check waits for 2 seconds for a response before timing out, are you sure this is the correct amount? Also did you check the indentation?

Comment: Those 2 seconds was just a test.
And the indentation was alright, it became like that because i turned it on comment.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to loop through questions and get the date after that make the embed. Below is an example of how to get the `Title` and `Description`. You can modify it how you like

```py
@client.command(aliases=["createEmbed", "embedCreate"])
async def embed(ctx):
    questions = ["Title?", "Description?"]
    responses = []

    def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel

    for question in questions:
        try:
            await ctx.send(question)
            message = await client.wait_for('message', timeout=15, check=check)

        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await ctx.send("Timeout")
            return

        else:
            responses.append(message.content)

    embedVar = discord.Embed(title=responses[0], description=responses[1])
    await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)
```

Comment: It didn't work, i'm starting to think the problem isn't at this command.
I'm not even getting an error.
The bot is sending the first question, i answer and nothing happen after that.

Comment: I double checked the code i sent at works on my end. Could you use [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) and send your whole code.

Comment: Sorry answer this late, school got me a lot of works. I pasted it here https://pastebin.com/KCkDVvNb, i didn't had time to organize, so i pasted a mess there , sorry.

As you can see there, i was in fury so i literally copy your exemple to see if it was working.